# Letting remote desktops access localhost's web service

Tags: eclipse, web-services, rest, jax-ws, remote-access

I can access my computer's (localhost) web service using eclipse mars and jax-ws. However, I'm just curious, how can I make it so that other remote computers that is not connected by LAN?

Any advice, direction, or what I should research is welcomed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Your computer is invisible to internet. It will connect to internet
  via a router (ADLS modern for en example).
- Your router is visible on Internet and with a public IP Address, you
  can try some website to see what its address is (for example
  http://whatismyipaddress.com/)
- You need to config your router to make it forward the request from internet
  to you computer LAN address and your web-service port, the way to
  config port forwarding is depend on your router.

Comment: Thank you, that definitely clears up some of my misunderstandings. But what if two computers have the same DNS? Will I still need to do port forwarding?

Comment: You dont need to do port forwaring if your two computer can see eachother directly, try "ping" command to check that

Comment: Thx! It is connected to each other. All I was missing was to add the web service port as an exception to the firewall's security.